# RGBA Overlay on carousel image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get a RGBA overlay on the slides in my Bootstrap carousel. I thought this would be pretty simple, but apparently not.

I have tried to use the :before selector to add the background, but with no luck.

```
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img, .img-responsive, .thumbnail a>img, .thumbnail>img:before {
    content:'\A';
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9htsmt9h/1/)

Comment: You need to add more details, how your html looks like? Can you prepare snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for someting like this:

```
.carousel-inner>.item {
    position: relative;
}

.carousel-inner>.item:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    top:0; 
    left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9htsmt9h/2/)